# How can I create bulk Hyperlinks (Parts 1 - 100)

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a website and I have come across the problem of having over 100 links and I don't know how to Hyperlink every single one.

Lets say I wanted to structure it like

```
<a href="link.com/1-5JKFKS" target="_blank">Part 1</>
<a href="link.com/2-5KWMAS" target="_blank">Part 2</>
<a href="link.com/3-42JNSL" target="_blank">Part 3</>
```

How would one go about creating 106 links formatted like this. I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for or even what is required to do this. So I'm sorry for how broad the question is.

I created a program in C# to create it for me. If anyone ever needs it I can give out the source code.

https://i.imgur.com/7csfx3V.gifv

Comment: Using only html? are you talking about a specific IDE/Editor? As your question currently stand it's either too broad or not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a web developer. I have 106 links and I'm trying to create 106 Hyperlinks in that format. I don't really mind how its done but obviously the less resources is better.

Currently thinking of making a program on C# to do this as there doesn't seem to be any public tools available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're asking for, but this would work as far as I can tell:

```js
var nOfLinks = 100;
for (var i = 1; i <= nOfLinks; i++) {
  document.getElementById("links").innerHTML += "<a href=\"link.com/" + i + "\" target=\"_blank\">Part " + i + "</><br/>"

}
```

```html
<div id="links">

</div>
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. This site is really unhelpful sometimes. If you don't have basic knowledge you aren't welcome. Should put that on the front as the landing page lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/) in the code editor you're using you can do it with something like this:

```
a[href="link.com/$" target="_blank"]{Part $}*106
```

With Emmet you just write this and usually press the `tab` key to expand the code into the full HTML.

That will output the links correctly.

Comment: I done this using C# instead because the links don't have a set number. Although this got me in the right direction. GIF of what I did.

https://i.imgur.com/7csfx3V.gifv